# Build error OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5.8

I have a working project on Qt 5.5 and I had to migrate to Qt 5.8 to use the new `QCharts` feature. When I tried to compile a working project (Qt 5.5) I get the following error;

> `:-1: error: no such file or directory: '5.8/5.8/clang_64/lib'`

What does this mean? How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE**
According to the comment I checked the director is missing;

[image: Directory Image]

Qt needs `'5.8/5.8/clang_64/lib'`

 But my system directory is: `5.8/clang_64/lib'`.

I added a `5.8` folder but then Qt reports it cannot locate the `qmake` file at `5.8/clang_64/lib'`.

What would be my next step?

Comment: This will need more information to be useful. What it means is pretty clear, how to resolve will require more information.

Comment: I mean I do know it says a 'certain' file is missing at the specified directory; but doesn't mention the 'name' of the file. i checked the directory, it has a range of files. What more info do you need? Thanks

Comment: @Vino It says certain file OR directory. In this case it seems to be indeed directory `[...]/lib`.

Comment: @Vino There may be different causes to this. First of all I would delete `pro.user` file from the project directory, then reload project.

Comment: @BlackMoses I tried it but it doesn't work. Thanks, Ill try at Qt official forum.

Comment: Any news on that error? I am getting the same and I can't figure out why

Comment: @FastBanana I didn't fix this problem because I used another 3rd party library for my purpose. But I presume the issue can be solved by renaming the root folder of your `Qt` installation as follows; `Qt\5.8\<other files>` instead of `Qt 5.8\5.8\<other files>`. I think because `Qt` requires the root folder to be named strictly as `Qt`.